# Should i make multiple models for my migration with different tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a migration with multiple tables in it: Status, Status_project, Status_task. Can i call them all with just my Status model that was created with migration command ?

```
php artisan make:model Status -m
```

I am reading at several places that i have to make a model for each table, but is there no other way? Except DB::table('statuses'). Because of my relations i don't prefer multiple models

Example:

```
  Schema::create('statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('display_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('status_task', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('task_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('status_id');

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('task_id')->references('id')->on('ongoing_tasks')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('status_id')->references('id')->on('statuses')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

    });

    Schema::create('status_project', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('project_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('status_id');

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('ongoing_projects')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('status_id')->references('id')->on('statuses')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

    });

    DB::commit();
```

Comment: laravel handles relations well there is no reason to avoid them and yes if your trying to make full use of laravel eloquent abilities you have to make a model for each table. see https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on using Eloquent to build your queries, you need to create a model for each table. If you are using the query builder, no need to create a model for each table.